# How to make a folder/directory

Tags: c++, directory

How do I make a directory/folder with c++. I've tried to use the mkdir() without success. I want to write a program that cin's a variable and then uses this variable to create sub-directory's and files with in those.
my current code. It says the + operator in the mkdir() says error no operand

```
char newFolder[20];

cout << "Enter name of new project without spaces:\n";
cin >> newFolder;
string files[] = {"index.php"};
string dir[] = {"/images","/includes","/includes/js","/contact","about"};

for (int i = 0; i<=5; i++){
mkdir(newFolder + dir[i]);
ofstream write ("index/index.php");
write << "<?php \n \n \n ?>";
write.close();
}
```

Comment: `mkdir()` is the right way to do it, at least on a POSIX system.  What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `#include <string>`, the `std::string` operators are defined in that header.

The result of the expression `newFolder + dir[i]` is a `std::string`, and `mkdir()` takes a `const char*`. Change to:

```
mkdir((newFolder + dir[i]).c_str());
```

Check the return value of `mkdir()` to ensure success, if not use `strerror(errno)` to obtain the reason for failure.

This accesses beyond the end of the array `dir`:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=5; i++){
    mkdir(newFolder + dir[i]);
```

there are `5` elements in `dir`, so legal indexes are from `0` to `4`. Change to:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    mkdir(newFolder + dir[i]);
```

Use`std::string` for `newFolder`, rather than `char[20]`:

```
std::string newFolder;
```

Then you have no concern over a folder of more than 19 characters (1 required for null terminator) being entered.

Comment: Thank you for your help I changed the for condition but it still says the same thing, I can't get past the error to see any output.

Comment: Again thank you but the + in the mkdir is still erroring it says no operator "+" matches these operands