# Cannot create a txt file using fstream::open

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have two files and in one I have created simple class :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
class myclass{ 
    protected:
        int ima,imb,imc,tm;
        fstream file;

 public: 
void creafile(string filename){ 
    string dir; 
    dir = "txtfile/"; 
    file.open((dir + filename).c_str(), ios::in | ios::out); 

    if(file.fail()){ 
    //  file.open(filename, ios::in | ios::out); 

      //if(file.fail()) 
      cout<<"Error when creating the file"<<endl; 
      exit(1); 
    } 
file.close(); 
}}
```

and my main file is called data.cpp and contain only this code:

```
using namespace std;
#include "mylib.h"
int main() {
    myclass dat,hi;
    dat.creafile("creatorfile.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I always get an error when calling `creafile` **Error when creating the file**. To make a simpler test case, I also tried the following code:

```
file.open("myfile.txt");
    if(!file){ 
      cout<<"Error when creating the file"<<endl; 
      exit(1); 
    } 
file.close();
```

However, it still gives the error **Error when creating the file**. I've tried using all flags `ios::app ios::in ios::out` etc but nothing changes. I have 500gb free space, and running Windows 7.

Comment: Maybe a small overlook, perhaps you need to run program as admin or such? Could be a possibility.

Comment: i tried everything.. doesnt  work .. its strange problem

Comment: try ../txtfile/ for your dir

Comment: Find your open mode: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open

Comment: no my data.cpp file is on dir informatic folder and also my class file. txtfile folder is also

Comment: but i without ios::app  iop::in etc   doesnot works

Comment: that link is useless

Comment: Are you sure you have created a the `txtfile` directory? That could be the problem. Also make sure that the directory is located in the working directory of the program.

Comment: i have tried at my school too but didnt work

Comment: can i declear std::fstream file.open("myfiletxt.txt",ios::app) in method ?

Comment: i have tried something like this   void creadata(string filename){
    int a=0;
      string dir,nome,cell,nomi_colone[a];

      dir = "txtfiles/" ;
      cout <<dir + filename<<endl;
      std::fstream fi; 
      fi.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::out);

    if(!ff){
      cout<<RED<<"Error durante la apertura del file"<<RESET<<endl;
      exit(1);
    }

    std::fi.close();
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1: You cannot open to read if the file doesn't exist. Fortunately you probably don't want to. Simultaneously reading and writing the same file is problematic and almost always a bad idea. Until you know you have to read and write at the same time,

1. open the file for reading
2. read in the file
3. close the file.
4. edit the file in memory
5. open the file for writing
6. write out the file
7. close the file

If you have a really big file you can't store in memory,

1. open the file for reading
2. open a temporary file for writing
3. read in part of the file
4. edit the part you read
5. write the part you read to temporary
6. if more file, goto 3 (but don't use `goto`), else continue
7. close file
8. close temporary file
9. delete file
10. rename temporary file to file

Point 2: You have created the txtfile folder, but have you created it in the right place? Your development environment (include of conio.h suggests Visual Studio or antique)  may not be running your program from where you think it is running.

Add this to your code in main:

```
char buf[4097]; // really big buffer
getcwd(buf, (int)sizeof(buf)); // get working directory
std::cout << buf << std::endl; // print the working directory
```

If the folder printed out is not where you made the txtfile folder, you can't open the file. If you want to automatically make the folder, read here: [How to make a folder/directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920278/how-to-make-a-folder-directory)

Point 3: `exit(1);` is a really big hammer. It is a nasty hammer. [Read more here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) Don't use it without a really, really good reason. In this case `return` is more than enough to get you out of the function, and if you add a return value to the function, `main` can test the return value to see if it should continue or return. Or you can throw an exception.

Comment: i found really your useful  explaintion but this is not answer of my question

Comment: @Phoenix one thing I missed when writing that is using perror to print out the cause of the error. [Documentation on perror.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t0e6085.aspx) You likely have two problems and hopefully knowing why the file didn't open will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open), `ios::in | ios::out` `std::ios_base::openmode` configuration will an generate error if the file does not exist, so you **won't** create a new one with that.

I don't know why you're using the member `std::fstream`, `createfile` could just be a `static` function that does not change any object. You're even closing it afterwards! It would create a file using a **local** `std::ofstream`, open mode of which is `std::ios_base::out`, which **will** create the file:

```
std::ofstream ofs(dir + filename); // .c_str() not needed since C++11
```

Comment: teachers teached yet only using namespace std; and not using std methods.. std::cout<<"blabla"<<endl; //this they didint teach us i learnt alone but i dont know very much about std

Comment: `fstream` and `string` come from `std`, too.

Comment: is there any other site where we colobrate with c++

Comment: What are you asking? Add a verb.

Comment: oops sorry why u use std::ofstream ofs if i have already use a library fstream and Declare variable type file(fstream file;)   ?

Comment: isnt it enough ? and @lalaland suggest me to use .c_str() first day work and when i compil 2nd day... it started giving me errorr

Comment: Then leave `.c_str` there. I'm using `std::ofstream`, it's local because you don't need it afterwards, after the function ends.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97904/discussion-between-phoenix-and-logicstuff).